# Can't deploy create-react-app application on GitHub Pages

Tags: github, create-react-app

I followed all the [steps](https://reactgo.com/deploy-react-app-github-pages/) necessary to deploy my `create-react-app` application (in conjunction with `react-router-dom`, `redux`, and `react-redux`) [here](https://bnikkhah.github.io/flags-of-the-world-redux/), but my app is not displaying anything but the *footer*.

I went to check out the console, but the console is completely clean of errors. Here is the *homepage* code I put in my `package.json` file.

package.json

```
"name": "flags-of-the-world-redux",
"homepage": "https://bnikkhah.github.io/flags-of-the-world-redux/",
[...],
"scripts": {
  [...],
  "predeploy": "yarn run build",
  "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
},
```

Here is my router:

CountryRouter.jsx

```
export default () => (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact={ true } path="/" component={ CountriesPage } />
            <Route path="/country/:name" component={ CountryPage } />
            <Route path="/compare" component={ CompareCountryList } />
        </Switch>
        <Footer />
    </BrowserRouter>
)
```

**Note:** my footer component displays correctly, but anything within the `Switch` are not displayed on my GitHub page.

Would anyone have any idea what other steps I need to follow in order to successfully deploy my React + Redux app?

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I decided to go with deploying on Heroku instead. I followed this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zDiQrgeGTuU) to get me started. If anybody would like to view my app, feel free [here](https://flags-of-the-world-redux.herokuapp.com/)!